# Transport-related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Three posts currently have the [transportation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) tag.  Two involve automobiles and one involves commercial aviation.   Questions regarding these topics have generally been tagged with [cars](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) and [aviation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation) respectively, and I just added those tags to two of them.

Should we keep an overarching [transportation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) tag, or are these topics better served by just their specific tags?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would lean toward a vehicle-specific tag. Larian may be able to say very interesting things about aircrafts, but he's probably less knowledgeable about cars and motorbikes.

Basically, I think "transportation" is just too large of an umbrella, with no experts.

Comment: That reminds me of something else that's been bugging me that I just added to my question.  (But that one might just be me being overly pedantic.  I worked my way through college at the campus library so I'm particular about taxonomies.  :-)

Comment: @Patches: That should be a separate question, really. Do keep in mind that, whatever you would suggest as an alternative, tags should be created by thinking of their audience. "What kind of person would have use for this tag?"

Comment: Rolled back.  I'll leave that issue alone for now, because even I'm not sure about it.

Comment: +1 - For vehicle specific. Seems more useful for me. Good point re: @Larian incidentally.